# How to create a common search in yii2 using PJAX and grid view

Tags: search, yii2, grid, pjax

I need to create a common search in yii2 grid which will search from all the column of grid view table.This is what I did so far.

**index.php**

```
<div class="pull-right">
  <?php yii\widgets\Pjax::begin(['id' => 'search-form' , 'timeout' => false,  'clientOptions' => ['method' => 'POST']]) ?>
    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['options' => ['data-pjax' => true ]]); ?>

            <?= $form->field($model, 'searchString')->textInput(['maxlength' => 200])->label(false) ?>
            <div class="form-group">
      <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? Yii::t('app', 'Create') : Yii::t('app', 'Update'), ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
     </div>

   <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
   <?php yii\widgets\Pjax::end() ?>
 </div>   
        <?php Pjax::begin(['id' => 'assets']); ?>            
         <?=
          GridView::widget([
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'filterModel' => $searchModel,
               /** column names **/  
                ]);
                ?>
         <?php Pjax::end(); ?> 

         $this->registerJs(
           '$("document").ready(function(){ 
           $("#search-form").on("pjax:end", function() {
             $.pjax.reload({container:"#assets"});  
            });
         });'
        );
```

Now when I submit searchbox didn't get desired result. Is there anything which I need to do to get output which I want. I looked from these links.

[Link1](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/772/pjax-on-activeform-and-gridview-yii2/)

[Link2](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/62747-search-data-using-ajax-in-yii2-not-pjax/)

Please help me to achieve this.

Comment: In common search you use _search.php and change query in your search model,pjax and search there is different things

Comment: But how can I call my custom search function @VishvaG

Comment: you just render like that <?= $this->render('_search', ['model' => $searchModel]); ?>

Comment: show your search model function